# Can I do Javascript development in Google Sheets on an Android phone or tablet?

Tags: javascript, android, google-sheets

It looks as though it needs to be on Windows/Linux/Mac OS's to work. On the Sheets app on my phone there doesn't seem to be the eqivalent of the menu option "Tools/Script editor" which is on Windows and Linux, using Chrome.

It seems like an anomoly as this stage - not to run on Android (or iOS?), especially given the power of eg my next phone Samsung Galaxy Note9.

To make my question clear, I'm talking about doing script development in Google Sheets on an Android phone or tablet, not Android app development on an Android device. I have been doing it on Chrome on Ubuntu Linux and Windows7, all are running the latest versions.